# PHP Object - how can I access this value

Tags: php

I have this link `http://lazhalazha.livejournal.com/data/rss` with RSS in it, what I need to get is array of `guid` values, that is links to the post. This is what I have so far...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://lazhalazha.livejournal.com/data/rss');
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item){
    print_r($item->guid);
}
```

Output is series of these objects

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [isPermaLink] => true
        )

    [0] => http://lazhalazha.livejournal.com/713.html
)
```

Solved this by converting this object to string, then it's passing correct URL instead of object.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://lazhalazha.livejournal.com/data/rss');
$linkArray = array();
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item){
    $guid = (string)$item->guid;
    array_push($linkArray, $guid);
}
```

Comment: What `does not work` about your 1st option?

Comment: @Neal output is same as without [0] at the end.

Comment: please go through the simplexml basic usage example in the php manual.

Comment: @Gordon by looking at simple example my code above should work fine.

Comment: `echo $item->guid;` will output the value. `(string) $item->guid` will return it. just as with any other simplexml element as well.

Comment: @Gordon well you should because it's correct one. And I didn't saw any reference to this on basic usage examples. Anyway figured out myself, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$_temp = array();
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://lazhalazha.livejournal.com/data/rss');

foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item){
    $_temp[] = (string)$item->guid[0];
}

print_r($_temp);
?>
```